# C# Changing an Existing class - Best Practice Open/Closed Principle

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out the best way to change an existing class.
So the class is called ExcelReport and it has one method Create(data,headings).
This is live and used in many places.
Now recently I want to change the method so I can format columns in excel.
Create(data,headings,columnformats)

So as not to upset my existing programs the best I can come up with is to add another method
Create2(data,headings,columnformats) to the class.

o.k I got a lot of suggestions saying I should modify the existing class with a overloaded method, which I did.
But does this not break the Open/Close Principle as my existing class was in production. Should I have created a new class ExcelReport2(and Interface) with the new improved method and passed this into my new program using dependency injection ?

Regards,
Niall

Comment: what's the problem with... well.. just adding a method to the class? and why not just make an overload `Create(data, headings, columnformats)`? if there's any reason why you can't do this, it'd be helpful if you included it in your question

Comment: Any overload would suffice just fine as @FranzGleichmann mentioned. Could you provide more details and clarity to your question?

Comment: o.k good point. But what is the best practice with a live class should it be left untouched ?Should I be creating a new class and an Interface that future programs should be passed ?

Comment: `Should I be creating a new class and an Interface that future programs should be passed` there's no need for that.

Comment: Just add an overload - it will be compatible with anything that already consumes the existing library. The idea is that you don't break your *public API* which is any part of your library that a consumer can see. Adding new methods to an existing class does not break the public API so it's safe and backwards compatible. The implementation could even change underneath that API and it would still work (assuming the implementation didn't do something weird and wonderful the consumer wasn't expecting).

Comment: Generally you can deal with compatibility between versions of applications by applying semantic versioning https://semver.org/ - it states that the version number of your application gives an idea as to the compatibility between versions. Of course these are guidelines and not following them strictly enough could mean incompatibilities, but if you design with this mindset it tends to prevent any clashes. Jon Skeet has a good blog post here that should give additional guidance https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/04/13/backward-compatibility-and-overloading/

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest the best approach is likely to use an overload method. In most cases I would approach this with the idea of implementing the overload method as a pass-through if possible.

```
Create(data, headings, columnformats)
```

would transform the data using the column formats and call:

```
Create(data,headings)
```

at the end of the method. This means in all cases of the Create method call the version with 2 parameters while the cases that need 3 are handled as a pass-through. This keeps to a rule of least disturbance and avoids confusion if the code needs to be maintained in the future since you are not duplicating the logic in:

```
Create(data,headings)
```

**Edit:** One important consideration with this approach is that if `columnformats` does not modify the data or headings you may not be able to practically use this as outlined. In that case you would use `Create(data, headings, columnformats)` as the base method with `Create(data,headings)` acting as a pass-through to that function. In this case `Create(data,headings)` would set a default value that is then passed to `Create(data, headings, columnformats)`

Comment: Good answer, though it's worth pointing out that depending on how `columnformats` work that it may be that the method with the most params does the work and the latter assumes a sensible default for the `columnformats` parameter of the former. It really does depend on the implementation though and your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Charleh excellent point I will add a note to my answer

Comment: o.k thanks - I sounds like a simple overloaded method is the answer and a new interface for my class to implement. My new program will then use the new Interface.